# YouTube API - Dynamically add event listeners

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube API to restyle embedded videos which are dynamically added to the page.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the custom controls. Each video embed has a custom control which needs to fire the `playVideo()` function on the relevant embed.

When each player is initialised it fires the onPlayerReady function. My problem is I don't know how to bind a click event to the new players custom button which will fire the `playVideo()` function for the correct player.

I've done a lot of searching on here and can't find reference to working with multiple embeds.

**FINAL UPDATE**

As jQuery is available, i'm using it in this solution...

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // bind events
  var playButton = $(event.target.c).parent().find('.immersive-video__play');
  playButton.on('click', function() {
    event.target.playVideo();
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is my current working solution...

```
var buttonCount = 0;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // bind events
  var playButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("immersive-video__play");
  playButtons[buttonCount].addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.target.playVideo();
  });

  buttonCount++;
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // bind event
  var playButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("immersive-video__play");

  // I don't know how to link the button to the player?
  playButtons[].addEventListener('click', function() {
      player[].playVideo();
  });

}

var player = [];

function checkYT() {
  var check = setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof YT !== 'undefined' && typeof YT.Player !== 'undefined') {
      var tar = document.getElementsByClassName('immersive-video__embed');

      for (var i = 0; i < tar.length; i++) {
        var id = tar[i].dataset.video;
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('video-holder');
        player[i] = new YT.Player(container[i], {
          videoId: id,
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      clearInterval(check);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('not ready');
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `iframe src` URL has `?enablejsapi=1` at the end like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
```

> Setting the parameter's value to 1 enables the player to be controlled via IFrame or JavaScript Player API calls. The default value is 0, which means that the player cannot be controlled using those APIs.

Check your Player object which has the ability to control that video. Create it using the `id` attribute on that iframe. Here is an example from this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/):

```
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}
```

Then check the "player ready" callback and bind events. It will automatically be passed the event object, in which `event.target` is the player.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {

  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });

  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });

}
```

Hope this helps!